# iOS and CouchDB Replication

Tags: ios, frameworks, couchdb, replication, pouchdb

I'm facing some difficulties in choosing  the best CouchDB/PouchDB iOS SDK. We have a CouchDB server that can not be upgraded or modified at the moment. This Is a problem for Couchbase Lit SDK last relaese because it uses Sync Gateway as its own server (no longer compatible with CouchDB).

So I studied a bit of `CDTDatastore`, the Cloudant SDK. Unfortunately is quite 'obsolete' at code level, in the sense that there are more than 100 warnings that I really don't like because are almost referring to object block capture (strong reference cycle) and deallocation of objects in the `finalize` responder thet is deprecated since years :-)

So I though, just because I'm nearly mad, to try to implement myself the replication protocol, but really, I know it is quite hard, just because, if I correctly understood, I need to implement a CouchDB instance on the iOS device.

So I have two related questions:

- Can you suggest me a SDK/Framework/Library to use to simply handling data locally and than manage replication into a CouchDB server? I'd like to be able to choose if use Objective-C or Swift if it is possible;
- Is there a way to create a very simple class that implement the replication protocol using only HTTP requests? Or implementing a CouchDB instance is a must?

So... shortly speaking... what is your preferred solution in situations like this?

Answer (score 0):

I use React Native which stopped me from using Couchbase Light (they abandoned project for RN) but their module seemed to work fine in iOS at least some time ago. 
It's compatible with CouchDB replication AFAIK.
For RN space I use PDB-localstorage in conjunction with CouchDB.

Comment: Yes I knew how it is 'easy' in RN... unfortunately our committer asked a real native iOS app because he need to integrate it in their projects... I read Couchbase Lite was compatible until v1.4 (if I remember correctly). So you say that even if they do not officially support CouchDB is stille working with Couchbase Lite 2.0?

Comment: Yes as I said there was compatibility, but it seems that in 2.0 they changed protocol. But why don't you consider integrate RN (thus PDB) as external module to existing iOS project? I heard it isn't that complicated. To my point it makes no big difference - which _anyway external_ module to put in.

Comment: Wow! This could sound good. Do you really think I can create a kind of library in RN exposing methods to an Xcode project? If it could be possible it could be a solution to be take into account!

Comment: Never did it (as I said I'm pure RN guy) but probably it's worth to dig a bit deeper: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps

Comment: Thanks Alex... Well... As you are a RN guy :-) Could you be able to understand what PouchDB.js does when call the `synch()` method? I mean... Do you think PouchDB recreate a real local CouchDB instance so that the iOS responds at... say http://iphoneip:5984/ ?? Well mmh... I think this is something of sci-fi :-) Maybe I miss something about replication between device and a server...

Comment: AFAIK PDB creates it's own local instance and communicates with attached storage via adapters (thus there are plenty of them). But anyway - in JS space (you can check PDB lib, it's open). What you are talking about - is Couchbase Lite implementation, other approach